# Compile Errors using bfd.h on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc

I am new to Linux programming and am attempting to use the BFD library. This is the current code I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <bfd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bfd *abfd;

int main() {
  bfd_init();
  abfd = bfd_openr("/home/mike/Desktop/testFunc/testProg", NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

I am using the following command line for compiling:

```
gcc readInfo.c /usr/lib/libbfd.a -o readInfo
```

And am getting the following errors:

> gcc readInfo.c /usr/lib/libbfd.a -o readInfo
>   /usr/lib/libbfd.a(elflink.o): In function
>   `elf_link_add_object_symbols':
>   /build/buildd/binutils-2.21.53.20110810/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/elflink.c:4605:
>   undefined reference to`objalloc_free_block'
>   /build/buildd/binutils-2.21.53.20110810/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/elflink.c:4892:
>   undefined reference to `_sch_istable' /usr/lib/libbfd.a(elflink.o): In
>   function`bfd_elf_size_dynamic_sections':
>   /build/buildd/binutils-2.21.53.20110810/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/elflink.c:6048:
>   undefined reference to `lbasename'
>   undefined reference to`_sch_istable' collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status make: *** [all] Error 1

There are a lot more lines of errors, which you can view [here](http://pastebin.com/Gn78mpiX). I'm sure there is a simple explanation for this but it has got me stumped for a while.

To summarise what I have done so far:

- Installed clean build of Ubuntu
- Installed binutils-dev package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to statically link your program?

It compiles and runs without error if you dynamically link it instead:

```
gcc readInfo.c -o readInfo -lbfd
```

I've run into a new problem when trying to make it statically linked:

```
$ gcc readInfo.c /usr/lib/libbfd.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a -o readInfo
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality
    in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making
    an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$ gcc -fPIE readInfo.c /usr/lib/libbfd.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a \
    -o readInfo
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality
    in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making
    an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$ gcc -fPIE -pie readInfo.c /usr/lib/libbfd.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a \
  -o readInfo
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: /usr/lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S
    against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with
    -fPIC
/usr/lib/libbfd.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$ gcc -fPIC -fPIE -pie readInfo.c /usr/lib/libbfd.a \
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a -o readInfo
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: /usr/lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S
    against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with
    -fPIC
/usr/lib/libbfd.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I didn't realise that what I was doing was statically linking. Is there a reason why statically linking would have caused these errors though?

Comment: The `/usr/lib/libbfd.so` depends upon other dynamic libraries for some of its functionality -- so the static `.a` version will also require those other static libraries when linking your final executable. I'm having trouble figuring out how to build it statically though.

Comment: Alright. Going to accept this answer since it fixes the immediate problem but if you I'd be very grateful if you eventually found how to correctly statically compile it too :)

Answer (score 27):

if you use ubuntu install binutils-dev

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-dev
```

Comment: And on Fedora it's `sudo dnf install binutils-devel`.

Answer (score 2):

gcc -v main.c -o blah /usr/lib64/libbfd.a /usr/lib64/libiberty.a -ldl -lz

Looks like libbfd requires features from libiberty, dl and z - this on opensuse 13.1 x86_64 today with similar trivial test app.