# Problem when compiling program using libbfd (bfd library)

Tags: c++, binary, analysis, bfd

Hi I have a problme please. When I try to compile a binary analysis tool that uses the bfd library with this command:

### g++ -std=c++11 -o loader_demo loader_demo.cc loader.o -lbfd

(I have compiled earlier the loader.o and it was successful) but with the command that I provided above I have this error:

### C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archures.o):archures.c:(.rdata$.refptr._sch_istable[.refptr._sch_istable]+0x0): undefined reference to `_sch_istable' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(bfd.o):bfd.c:(.text+0x159): undefined reference to` xstrerror' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(bfd.o):bfd.c:(.text+0x16b1): undefined reference to `cplus_demangle' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(bfd.o):bfd.c:(.text+0x1797): undefined reference to` cplus_demangle' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(hash.o):hash.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `objalloc_create' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(hash.o):hash.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to` objalloc_free' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(hash.o):hash.c:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `_objalloc_alloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(hash.o):hash.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to` objalloc_free' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(hash.o):hash.c:(.text+0x2e9): undefined reference to `_objalloc_alloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(hash.o):hash.c:(.text+0x3df): undefined reference to` _objalloc_alloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(hash.o):hash.c:(.text+0x5c8): undefined reference to `_objalloc_alloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(hash.o):hash.c:(.text+0x7cd): undefined reference to` objalloc_free' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `objalloc_free' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0x4e1): undefined reference to` lrealpath' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0x70e): undefined reference to `stpcpy' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0x824): undefined reference to` objalloc_create' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0x973): undefined reference to `objalloc_free' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0xa2f): undefined reference to` xstrdup' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0xb96): undefined reference to `xstrdup' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0xc0e): undefined reference to` xstrdup' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0xd6e): undefined reference to `xstrdup' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0xf64): undefined reference to` _objalloc_alloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0x1477): undefined reference to `xstrdup' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0x17e8): undefined reference to` lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0x1940): undefined reference to `lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(opncls.o):opncls.c:(.text+0x1578): undefined reference to` objalloc_free_block' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(targets.o):targets.c:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `fnmatch' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(ihex.o):ihex.c:(.text+0xa6b): undefined reference to` hex_init' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(ihex.o):ihex.c:(.rdata$.refptr._hex_value[.refptr._hex_value]+0x0): undefined reference to `_hex_value' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(srec.o):srec.c:(.text+0x5ff): undefined reference to` hex_init' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(srec.o):srec.c:(.text+0x183e): undefined reference to `hex_init' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(srec.o):srec.c:(.text+0x192e): undefined reference to` hex_init' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(tekhex.o):tekhex.c:(.text+0xc2f): undefined reference to `hex_init' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(verilog.o):verilog.c:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to` hex_init' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(pex64igen.o):pex64igen.c:(.text+0x3e79): undefined reference to `xmalloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(pei-x86_64.o):pei-x86_64.c:(.text+0x2a0c): undefined reference to` xmalloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(pei-x86_64.o):pei-x86_64.c:(.text+0x2ddc): undefined reference to `xmalloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf64-x86-64.o):elf64-x86-64.c:(.text+0x512): undefined reference to` htab_traverse' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elfxx-x86.o):elfxx-x86.c:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to `htab_delete' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elfxx-x86.o):elfxx-x86.c:(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to` objalloc_free' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elfxx-x86.o):elfxx-x86.c:(.text+0x4c9): undefined reference to `htab_find_slot_with_hash' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elfxx-x86.o):elfxx-x86.c:(.text+0x566): undefined reference to` _objalloc_alloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elfxx-x86.o):elfxx-x86.c:(.text+0x688): undefined reference to `htab_try_create' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elfxx-x86.o):elfxx-x86.c:(.text+0x694): undefined reference to` objalloc_create' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elfxx-x86.o):elfxx-x86.c:(.text+0xc04): undefined reference to `htab_traverse' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf64.o):elf64.c:(.text+0x253e): undefined reference to` xstrdup' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elflink.o):elflink.c:(.text+0xc12b): undefined reference to `objalloc_free_block' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elflink.o):elflink.c:(.text+0xda84): undefined reference to` lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elflink.o):elflink.c:(.text+0xdb7f): undefined reference to `lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elflink.o):elflink.c:(.text+0x12da0): undefined reference to` xmalloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf-eh-frame.o):elf-eh-frame.c:(.text+0x21a1): undefined reference to `iterative_hash' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf-eh-frame.o):elf-eh-frame.c:(.text+0x21b3): undefined reference to` iterative_hash' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf-eh-frame.o):elf-eh-frame.c:(.text+0x21df): undefined reference to `iterative_hash' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf-eh-frame.o):elf-eh-frame.c:(.text+0x21f1): undefined reference to` iterative_hash' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf-eh-frame.o):elf-eh-frame.c:(.text+0x2203): undefined reference to `iterative_hash' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf-eh-frame.o):elf-eh-frame.c:(.text+0x2215): more undefined references to` iterative_hash' follow C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf-eh-frame.o):elf-eh-frame.c:(.text+0x22ef): undefined reference to `htab_find_slot_with_hash' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf-eh-frame.o):elf-eh-frame.c:(.text+0x27c0): undefined reference to` htab_try_create' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf-eh-frame.o):elf-eh-frame.c:(.text+0x28b9): undefined reference to `htab_delete' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(peigen.o):peigen.c:(.text+0x3ec9): undefined reference to` xmalloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf32-i386.o):elf32-i386.c:(.text+0x4d2): undefined reference to `htab_traverse' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(elf32.o):elf32.c:(.text+0x25d4): undefined reference to` xstrdup' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(plugin.o):plugin.c:(.text+0x6b6): undefined reference to `concat' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(plugin.o):plugin.c:(.text+0x6cf): undefined reference to` make_relative_prefix' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(plugin.o):plugin.c:(.text+0x744): undefined reference to `concat' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x2b7): undefined reference to` getpwd' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x2c4): undefined reference to `lrealpath' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x2d6): undefined reference to` lrealpath' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x4f4): undefined reference to `filename_ncmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x953): undefined reference to` htab_find' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x9d5): undefined reference to `htab_find_slot' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0xa2f): undefined reference to` htab_create_alloc' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0xec7): undefined reference to `lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0xfc4): undefined reference to` filename_cmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0xff8): undefined reference to `filename_cmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x1119): undefined reference to` xstrdup' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x1aef): undefined reference to `filename_cmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x1c03): undefined reference to` filename_cmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x1cb4): undefined reference to `lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x1ce7): undefined reference to` filename_ncmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x1d8f): undefined reference to `filename_ncmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x1ec4): undefined reference to` lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x1fb5): undefined reference to `lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x20db): undefined reference to` lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x22b4): undefined reference to `lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x2342): undefined reference to` lbasename' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x23c4): more undefined references to `lbasename' follow C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x3624): undefined reference to` htab_find_slot' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x3651): undefined reference to `htab_clear_slot' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x36e2): undefined reference to` htab_traverse_noresize' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(archive.o):archive.c:(.text+0x36ea): undefined reference to `htab_delete' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(cache.o):cache.c:(.text+0x389): undefined reference to` unlink_if_ordinary' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `inflateInit_' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to` inflateReset' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `inflate' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to` inflateEnd' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x653): undefined reference to `compressBound' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x684): undefined reference to` compress' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(corefile.o):corefile.c:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `filename_cmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(syms.o):syms.c:(.text+0x809): undefined reference to` filename_ncmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(syms.o):syms.c:(.text+0xcf9): undefined reference to `filename_cmp' C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(syms.o):syms.c:(.rdata$.refptr._sch_toupper[.refptr._sch_toupper]+0x0): undefined reference to` _sch_toupper' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

And I need some help to resolve the problem. And thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile Errors using bfd.h on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003763/compile-errors-using-bfd-h-on-linux)

Comment: I am using windows with bfd library

Comment: is it possible to solve the error under windows (because I am using libbfd to analyse PE file on windows)